# Filtering playstore availability just for android phones

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, android-sdk-manager

I am about to publish an app to google playstore. On device catalog section, I filtered SDK version how i wanted to be but;

I want my app to be installed only at **phones**, so not tablets or any other devices. I could not find the proper filter; or I dont know if i need to change something on bundle configuration

Any hints on that ?

Thanks for your assist

Answer (score 0):

Here how I solved this;

add the **telephony** feature with **required:true** prop to your **androidmanifest.xml** file under manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

Now lots of android tablets, tvs etc eliminated but tablets with call feature are still there.

After that, on Play Console, go to related app page > device catalog > filter > form factor > **Tablet**

Select all tablet devices supported and restrict them (Might be so many)

Hit OK

And now app should be only downloaded from android smartphones.